# c# datagridview set new row position on top

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

is there any way to set the last empty row on the top of the DataGridView ?
it annoys with large dataset to scroll to the last row to add a new one.
[image]

Comment: You can scroll the NewRow in a visible position inside the DataGridView's client area, just not the only Row visible. How do you want to trigger this action? Clicking the Cell in the upper-left corner?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to move the add new row to the top of a datagridview.  There is a control called the bindingSource which has methods like MoveLast to make it easier to navigate to last row of data.

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<DataInfo> data = new BindingList<DataInfo>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
        {
            data.Add(new DataInfo()
            {
                id = x,
                Name = $"User{x}"
            });
        }

        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.MoveLast();
    }
}

public class DataInfo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's a simple way to move the NewRow in the visible area of a DataGridView. There's a property for that.

Comment: @Jimi can you please tell me what the name of this property ?

Comment: `[DataGridView].FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = [DataGridView].NewRowIndex;`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the difference between an "Empty row" and the "Add new Row", which seems to be an empty row, but which in fact is not part of your data yet.

### Real Empty Rows on top

Suppose our DataGridView shows several properties of a sequence of Customers.

To get the empty rows on top, you'll have to define "Empty row":

- Is it the row where every displayed Customer property has a null value?
- Or should I check all Customer properties, even the non-displayed ones?
- And what about value types? When are they considered to be empty? If they have a value 0?
- And what about a displayed DateTime?

Questions, questions. Apparently you need to extend your Customer with a property IsEmpty:

```
public bool IsEmpty => ... // TODO code that returns true if customer is "Empty".
```

In order to sort such that the Empty Customers are on top, you need to create a CustomerComparer class, a class that implements `IComparer<Customer>`,
and tell the DataGridView to sort using this comparer:

```
IComparer<Customer> customerComparer = ...
this.DataGridView1.Sort(customerComparer);
```

An example of a Customer Comparer class:

```
class CustomerComparer<Tproperty> : Comparer<Customer>
{
    public bool EmptyRowsFirst {get; set;} = true;

    // sort the non-empty customers ascending or descending:
    public SortDirection SortDirection {get; set;} = SortDirection.Ascending;

    // which property to use to sort the non-empty customers:
    public Func<Customer, TProperty> PropertySelector

    public override int Compare (Customer x, Customer y)
    {
         if (this.EmptyRowsFirst)
         {
             if (x.IsEmpty)
                return y.IsEmpty ? 0 : +1
             else
                return y.IsEmpty ? -1 : this.CompareByProperty;
         }
         else
             return this.CompareByProperty;
    }
}
```

Method CompareByProperty:

```
private int CompareByProperty(Customer x, Customer y)
{
    IComparer<TProperty> propertyComparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    TProperty propertyX = this.PropertySelector(x);
    TProperty propertyY = this.PropertySelector(y);
    int compareResult = propertyComparer(propertyX, propertyY);
    if (this.SortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
        compareResult = -compareResult;
    return compareResult;
}
```

Usage:

```
// Sort by Customer.BirthDay, Ascending, empty rows First:
IComparer<Customer> customerComparer = new CustomerComparer<DateTime>
{
     EmptyRowsFirst = true,
     SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending,
     customer => customer.BirthDay,
};
this.DataGridView.Sort(customerComparer);

// Sort by Customer.City, rest as default:
IComparer<Customer> customerComparer = new CustomerComparer<String>
{
     customer => customer.City,
};
this.DataGridView.Sort(customerComparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an empty DataGridView (Dgv) with possibility to add new data.

The typical code for Dgv is (considering BindingSourceOject is assigned to ContextObject.DataSource):

```
    ContextObject.DBSetObject.Load();
    BindingSourceOject.DataSource = ContextObject.DBSetObject.Local.ToBindingList();
```

If do not load DBSet (remove the first line), Dgv will appear empty but connected to DBSetObject. It will show the data entry row only. New rows will appear here while being added.

The solution for the hole data processing form is to put two Dgvs on it. The first one is 'empty' as described above for data adding and another one with no data entry (AllowUserToAddRows = false) to view/edit existing data.

This solution deliver us from creating a set of controls to add data. Two Dgvs can share same event handlers for data validation, formatting etc.